# RESTful GET request with secured parameters

Tags: rest

I have to create search api endpoint like `/messages`

with pagination and ordering like `?page=1&ordering=ASC`

and also with some specific parameter, that should be a part of search process and also totally secured, like `super_secret_key=value`

So now I just use it with `POST` method and request body like

```
POST /messages
{
  "page": 1,
  "ordering": "ASC",
  "super_secret_key": "value"
}
```

But as I understand it violates RESTful rules, because it should be `GET`, and now I also can't use `POST /messages` for message creating.

Is there maybe better approach to implement searching like this in meaning of RESTful?

Comment: What do you mean by "secured"? Hidden from the URL in logs and such? Then use a header

Comment: Sensitive data must not be passed via GET so there is no violation. What exact violation are you talking about?

Comment: @Clashsoft Yeah, header can be an option, is there maybe some other variant?

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko Getting resources with POST

Comment: https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/#post `Apart from resource creation, POST should be also used for scenarios that cannot be covered by the other methods sufficiently.`

Comment: Header is pretty standard for API keys and such. Maybe your key falls under that.